# xlpagertabstrip some labels not fully displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

am using XLpagertabstrip in my application .. but i have a problem that the text is bigger than the width and it got cut from both sides .. like image below:

[image]

as you can see last tab which is المواجهات المباشرة is not displayed fully..

this is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    containerView.isScrollEnabled = false
    containerView.delegate = self

    self.settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 7)
    self.settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 1.0
    self.settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0.1
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = UIColor.white
    self.settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailableWidth = true
    self.settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    self.settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0
    self.settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 1.0

    changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
        guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
        //oldCell?.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        //newCell?.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        oldCell?.label.textColor = UIColor.white
        newCell?.label.textColor = UIColor.white
        oldCell?.label.font = UIFont(name: "AJannatLT", size: 14)!
        newCell?.label.font = UIFont(name: "AJannatLT", size: 14)
        newCell?.label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        oldCell?.label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        self?.buttonBarView.selectedBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    getMatchInfo()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = " "

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

but this will only change it's font size if i tabbed it ...

how to solve this? i want it from the start to be fully displayed and fit cell's width ..

Comment: how are you creating cell  ? is it custom cell with its own class ?

Comment: @Tobi its created by xlpagertabstrip.. i didn't create it or customized it .. am using the library's default

Comment: oh alright, great.

Comment: try setting the label.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: @George did not work :(

Comment: keeping the numberOfLines = 0 increase the label height. If that did not work try reducing the font size to lower values and see if the full text appears. Just to make sure that text is there.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @George it did not work with me sadly

Comment: then you need to check the library you are using I suspect that the library is overriding the numberOfLines property

Answer (score 0):

> but i have a problem that the text is bigger than the width and it got cut from both side

You can try `lineBreakMode`

```
label.lineBreakMode = .ByCharWrapping
```

Read more about [LineBreakMode](https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/5022/linebreakmode).

Comment: sadly got the same result as my posted screenshot :(

Comment: try to move super.viewDidLoad to the bottom of the method, sounds weird but could work

Comment: sadly it did not :(